# Whole Home Water Filter Installation Questions

Tags: plumbing, water, installation, filter

I bought a GE whole home water filter to install (GXWH35F) and am trying to figure out which one of these lines I need to install it on. I'm guessing the red pipe is hot water out of the heater. I was expecting a line in and two lines out but this is all I can see. Both pipes run behind the water heater and under the house.

Finally, the filter is meant to be mounted to the wall. Could I reroute these pipes to run horizontal and then back down to install the filter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the main shutoff to the house?  Any possibility of mounting it there?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to filter the whole house you need the line upsteam of where it branches to the water heater.  Anything in this area would only filter hot water.  It sounds to me like this is probably under your house.